# how to pass array form mailer to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help pass array form mailer to view.

app/mailers/send_mailer.rb:

```
class SendMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'no-reply@kalinin.ru'

  def sends_send(sends, emails, current_user_email)
    @log = []

    @log.push('--------------------------------------------------------------------')
    @log.push('send log for ' + current_user_email + ' :: started at ' + Time.now.to_s)

    sends.each do |send|
      emails.each do |email|
        @send = send
        @email = email

        if mail(to: email.email, subject: send.subject)
          @log.push('OK:: email: ' + email.email + ' :: send: ' + send.id.to_s + ' :: send_at: ' + Time.now.to_s)
        else
          @log.push('FAIL:: email: ' + email.email + ' :: send: ' + send.id.to_s + ' :: send_at: ' + Time.now.to_s)
        end
      end  
    end  
    puts @log
  end  
end
```

app/controllers/sends_controller.rb:

```
def send_up
  @sends = Send.where(user_id: current_user.id) 
  @emails = Email.where(user_id: current_user.id) 

  SendMailer.sends_send(@sends, @emails, current_user.email).deliver_now

  redirect_to log_index_path
end
```

after press button on main page, performed action 'send_up' and performed send_mailer.rb. array @log is filled and output to console. but i need display @log into view. but view now is empty

app/views/log/index.rb:

```
<h1>Log#index</h1>
<%= @log %>
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'log/index'
  ........
  ........
  ..........
end
```

rake routes:

```
log_index GET    /log/index(.:format)                      log#index
```

please help pass @log into view.

Comment: FYI, it is much better to do `"send log for #{current_user_email} :: started at #{Time.now.to_s}"` instead of `'send log for ' + current_user_email + ' :: started at ' + Time.now.to_s` - it's more readable, more terse and less brittle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance variables defined inside a model method will not be available in the controller, or any other class, which calls that model method.  However, if you want you can return the value of the variable at the end of the method, and then make sure you set some other variable equal to that.  For example, in your `sends_sends` (that's a very confusingly named method btw) method, change the last line from `puts @log` to `@log`.

Then in the controller, change

```
SendMailer.sends_send(@sends, @emails, current_user.email).deliver_now
```

to

```
@log = SendMailer.sends_send(@sends, @emails, current_user.email).deliver_now
```

Comment: but `code`@log = SendMailer.sends_send(@sends, @emails, current_user.email).deliver_now`code` its `code`<%= @log.class %>`code` output `code`Mail::Message`code` . its no log-array

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't understand your comment.